# VueJs CLI import/compile html string to vue

Tags: html, templates, vue.js, compilation

I'm looking for a solution to import my html string into my VueJs component and to be able to execute any VueJs code present in the html code.
I'm using VueJs (2.5.x) + CLI to run the `vue` app and few seconds after running, It make a request to the API to retrieve the HTML codes.

HTML code (after import and clicked on the card, I should be able to change `accessCardId` data) :

```
<div class="md-card md-theme-default" v-on:click="accessCardId = '5bfc54cf553b485038333ee5'">
        <div class="md-card-media">
          <img src="/icons/europa.jpg" alt="People" class="icon">
        </div>
        <div class="md-card-header">
          <div class="md-title">Europa</div>
          <div class="md-subhead">Every where, you can us...</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

VueJs Script (in home.vue) :

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Home',
    props: {
      msg: String
    },
    data: () => ({
      listCards: null,
      currentPage: -1,
      accessCardId: null
    }),
    filters: {
      shortDescription: description =>
        `${description.substring(0, 150)}${description.length > 150 ? '...' : ''}`
    },
    methods: {
      async loadPage() {
        await this.$http.get(`${process.env.VUE_APP_SERVER_URL}/icos?token=${process.env.VUE_APP_SERVER_TOKEN}&page=${this.currentPage + 1}`)
          .then(async res => {
            this.currentPage = this.currentPage + 1;
            // res.body === my html code
          });
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `v-html`directive which is used to render a static html content that doesn't require any event handling or data binding, and according to [official doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML):

> The contents of the `span` will be replaced with the value of the `rawHtml` property, interpreted as plain HTML - data bindings are ignored. Note that you cannot use `v-html` to compose template partials, because Vue is not a string-based templating engine. Instead, components are preferred as the fundamental unit for UI reuse and composition

another solution is to use the package `v-runtime-template`  found in https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template

This is probably useful for your use case, with all the usual concerns about safety of these approaches against malicious injections.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't works. Click events are just ignored plus it isn't interpreted by VueJs. `you cannot use v-html to compose template partials, because Vue is not a string-based templating engine`

Comment: @user9529080 i updated my answer by adding some details

Comment: you should one root element in your template like `<template><div>all the content</div></template>` not like `<template><div>some content</div><div>some other content</div></template>`

Comment: it doesn't works with `<template><div></div></template>` but when remove `<template>` balise it works ! Thank you ! For ex: `<div>all content</div>`